# How To Build Child Modules In Tycho

Tags: tycho

I have a multi-module Tycho build with a target definition file. The target definition is defined in it's own project (ID: `org.acme.project.target`, packaging type: `pom`) like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifacts>
                            <artifact>
                                <file>platform_rcp.target</file>
                                <type>target</type>
                                <classifier>platform_rcp</classifier>
                            </artifact>
                        </artifacts>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And the Maven parent refers to this target platform like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <resolver>p2</resolver>
        <target>
            <artifact>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.acme.project.target</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <classifier>platform_rcp</classifier>
            </artifact>
        </target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This setup works as long as I build the parent project. When I build one of the child modules, even if this project duplicates the reference to the target platform OR even when I build the parent with `mvn install -pl org.acme.project` I get the following exception:

```
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve target platform specification artifact myGroup:org.acme.project.target:target:platform_rcp:2.3.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
 org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve target platform specification artifact myGroup:org.acme.project.target:target:platform_rcp:2.3.0-SNAPSHOT
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:121)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
```

Even [the Tycho example](http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho-demo.git/tree/itp04-rcp/) doesn't work for me, but brings the same error message (`Could not resolve target platform specification artifact example.group:mars:target:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`).

I thought [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101847/how-to-use-the-same-target-platform-multiple-sub-projects-in-tycho) was similar, but my setup is exactly what is said to work in the answer.

What did I do wrong?

*(The actual problem in question is [that Eclipse Mars can't run integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657010/junit-plug-in-tests-ignoring-target-platform), so I can only use Tycho to run them, which needs a long time when Tycho builds all modules.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> even when I build the parent with mvn install -pl org.acme.project I get the following exception:

Have you tried prepending the target platform project to the list of `-pl` arguments: `mvn install -pl :mars,org.acme.project`

I use this all the time.

Comment: Note for the next person: You need to tediously collect all the dependencies and add them to the arguments. In the above example, where I only wanted to run the integration tests, the arguments would look like: `mvn install -pl org.acme.project.target,org.acme.project,org.acme.it`.

Comment: Yes, in theory one should be able to use the `-am` option (“also make”) in conjunction with `-pl to add the projects’ dependencies automatically. Unfortunately, [Bug 494760](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494760) and possibly others prevent this at the moment.